Why don't jets fly in the mesophere?
I've seen explanations for why commercial airliners don't reach these altitudes but so far I haven't run across any explanation of how increased speed might make up for low atmospheric density with experimental aircraft.
What if an aircraft was dropping out of orbit, sprouted winglets and turned on its ramjets? Certainly it could greatly increase its time of descent.
I believe there's a simple answer, perhaps the increased weight of fuel or engines can't be made up by airfoil efficiency, etc. So with all due respect what is it?

Commercial aircraft: Likely answered in Why are many jet aircraft designed to cruise around FL350-370? Which additional points would you like to be clarified? For other aircraft: Are there any aircraft designed to operate between an altitude of 50-80km?

I mean, once you get above the stratosphere, the air pressure is practically space. The mesosphere is kind of a pain for scientists because it's really hard to take long-term readings. Too much drag for a satellite, but not enough air to support any form of balloon or aerodynamic flight. Basically limited to sounding rockets and other extremely brief visits.


increased speed might make up for lower atmospheric density

Correct!  This is why true airspeed increases with altitude, while indicated airspeed, or ram pressure, can be constant.
This little trick allows airliners to reach 600 mph while their airspeed gauge reads only 250 mph.
This means the aircraft, pushing through thinner air, gets better miles per gallon until ...
The "sound barrier".  Supersonic flight increases drag.
Next is the "thermal barrier".  At very high speeds passing through air creates a substantial amount of heat from friction.  This is why meteors burn up when they enter the atmosphere.
The air in the Mesosphere is so thin that an aircraft would have to be going thousands of miles per hour to create sufficient lift.  It's been tried with the X-15 experimental aircraft.

"an aircraft would have to be going thousands of miles per hour to create sufficient lift." and the Karman line is the altitude at which the lift created by velocity is smaller than the centrifugal force, and therefore orbiting takes over flying. This is why this line is recognized as the limit atmosphere/space.

Was the X-15 actually able to generate usable lift in the mesosphere, or were they just a rocket at that point, launching through the mesosphere in an aerodynamic stall?

@DarthPseudonym. Many of the X-planes may have been lost for exactly that reason once the engine cut out and the aircraft started to sink.  This is probably why Virgin Galactic went to great lengths to develop their "feathering" system.

Maybe you meant "It's been tried and failed with the X-15", then?  I was under the impression that they never managed to generate significant lift or even aerodynamic control at those altitudes.  IIRC they had RCS thrusters for attitude.

@DarthPseudonym there is something called a flight envelope.  RCS may not have been needed all the time.  The X-15 flew nearly 200 times.  Certainly not a failure.  But they did have issues with heating from atmospheric friction.

@RobertDiGiovanni I'm wondering why less atmosphere/more speed would generate more heat than more atm/less speed. Does it involve the v term in the momentum formula being squared?

@TomRussell it may involve the behavior of each individual molecule hitting the aircraft surface.  And yes, their kinetic energy would be a v$^2$ function.
